# Update R formula: how to remove some of the interactions

Tags: r

suppose I have two factor objects and factor1 has three levels A,B,C and factor2 has two levels "placebo" and "treatment".

I want to create a formula object that contains all the interactions between factor1 and factor2 except the interactions between factor1C and all the levels of factor2. That is, I want:

```
 formula <- response ~ 1 + factor1A:factor2treat + factor1B:factor2treat+factor1A:factor2placebo+ factor1B:factor2placebo
```

In my actual scenario, factor1 has more than three levels hence I would like to define the formula in smarter way.

I tried:

```
formula <- response ~ factor1:factor2 - factor1C:factor2placebo - factor1C:factor2treat
```

However this gives me warning message..

Comment: Try quotation marks around the right-hand side of the `<-` arrow. And if you want to create a "formula object" look at the documentation by typing `?formula` in the console.

Comment: You need to post str() on the dataset. I'm guessing there is no variable named `factor1C` but that you are seeing that as hte output from a mdoel.